# .htaccess works in local but not on server (but no 404 error)

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess that is supposed to rewrite my URL. My host has told me that it supports URL rewriting, and I verified that by using phpinfo() and checking.

Anyways, this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [R]
```

It works like a charm in local, but on my server, it doesn't do anything.

I checked this before on the internet and some people had it, but they all had a 404 error, while I don't have a 404 error. It simply doesn't redirect, it doesn't do anything, so I get all kind of error messages.

Comment: is mod_rewrite turn on on your server?

Comment: Use this code to display the installed modules, and upload it to your server and navigate to the page: `<?php phpinfo(8); ?>`

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is turned on. ANy other suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure that the file (!-f) or directory (!-d) that you're matching doesn't exist before the rewrite. That way you don't end up with a 500 loop with something like `/index.php?page=index`. Additionally the `^` character is matching the beginning of the string, so if your original test was in a subdirectory it would not rewrite since you weren't allowing slashes.

This should work for any instance, however it will ONLY make the page variable the last string in the URI.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> `RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [R]`

The regex in your rule doesn't match strings with slashes at any position. I am not sure that's acceptable and you don't give any request examples, but I don't think it is.

You may try this rule-set in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1    [L]
```

For permanent redirection replace [L] with [R=301,L].

Comment: Thanks for the help. This didn't work for me (500 internal error, and in local it doesn't work either. Any other ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Modified my answer for a single 1st level directory. If still have a 500 error, there has to be more code in the .htaccess file that's missing in your question.